# How do you correctly use an iFrame in a CSS grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website where I have a simple centered title at the top, a navigation bar right under it, and I'm trying to have after that a block of text on the left, some padding, and a YouTube video on the right. To do this, I decided to use CSS grids, so I made the two elements (the iFrame and the text) divs and then added those two inside another div. Here is my css and html code:

```css
.middletop{
    width: 90%
    margn: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    gr
    grid-template-colums: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wordshere{
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
   <section>
       <div class="middletop">
           <div class="wordshere">
              Welcome to Quechua Plugs,
           </div>
           <div class="picthere">
               <iframe
                   width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yGw4Y8Zc9Jk"
                   frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                   allowfullscreen>
               </iframe>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

Anyway, when I reloaded my page, the video was under the word block, even though I specified columns in my code.

I'm just starting out using html and css, maybe there is an easier way to make these kinds of sections on websites? If not, can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in your code. The main problem is that you have `grid-template-colums: 1fr 1fr` when you need `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` Also you misspelled `margin` and there was a free floating `gr` that was breaking things too. Replace your `middletop` class with this:

```
.middletop{
    width: 90%
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead of `1fr` and fix your rules:

```css
.middletop{
    width: 90%
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.wordshere{
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
   <section>
       <div class="middletop">
           <div class="wordshere">
              Welcome to Quechua Plugs,
           </div>
           <div class="picthere">
               <iframe
                   width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yGw4Y8Zc9Jk"
                   frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                   allowfullscreen>
               </iframe>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

Comment: It turned out my mistake was just having typos in my code, but could you explain why you told me to use minmax() instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding class = "wrapper" in the section tag, this will help in to adjust the text on the left and the video on right. Even you have few typos in your code. The below once is working fine with me.

```
 <section class="wrapper">
       <div class="middletop">
           <div class="wordshere">
              Welcome to Quechua Plugs,
           </div>
           <div class="picthere">
               <iframe
                   width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yGw4Y8Zc9Jk"
                   frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                   allowfullscreen>
               </iframe>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


.middletop{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wordshere{
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Here are my changes in your code [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/divya661/16orfjka/4/)